# Yii Gii Crudcode Object Access The Model of Our Input

Tags: php, forms, yii, crud, gii

i'm trying to modify my gii... that's legal isn't it??

I'm trying to modify crud form generator so that the generator will generate form for current relational model..

i can do that if i modify the CActiveFormWidget, but it dont generate the code to the _form file...

so i need to modify the form by gii CRUD generator.

how do i access and create/instantiate the Model supplied by our input?

I could only get the Model class name.. What i need is the model it self..

EDITED :

Found it!

simply just :

```
$obj = new $this->modelClass();
```

at file _form.php

Yay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other solution :

```
$obj = new $this->getModelClass();
```

btw, do you have tried yiibooster ? http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/

Comment: i've tried, and install it.. but it doesn't generate any relation form..looks like it just beautify the form...:D is there any widget that could generate relation form(belongs to and has many is my priority)